# Gutenberg - Call google map render function in save after DOM has been rendered

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have a bit of a dilemma.

In the `save` function I need to call a function `renderMap` that renders a dynamic google map. However I need to call it after the DOM has been rendered. I can't seem to find a solution for this. I realised you can't add a class to the `save` function with the React lifecycle so I am stopped. It does work for the `edit` function though. What are the possibilities?

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } from '@wordpress/edit-post';
import { Component } from '@wordpress/element';

const renderMap = function() {
    let googleMap = document.getElementById('google-map')
    let map
  map = new google.maps.Map(googleMap, {
    center: { lat: 37.79406, lng: -122.4002 },
    zoom: 14,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
  })
}

registerBlockType( 'splash-blocks/google-maps', { 
    title: __('Google maps locations', 'google-maps'),
    icon: 'megaphone',
    category: 'common',
    keyword: [
        __( 'Display Google maps locations' ),
    ],
    atrributes: {
        markers: {
            type: 'object'
        },
    address: {
        type: 'string',
        default: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        }, 
        api_key: {
        type: 'string',
        default: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        }
    },
    edit: class extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props)
      }

     componentDidMount() {
            renderMap()
        }

        render() {
            const { attributes, setAttributes } = this.props

            return ( 
                <div id='google-map'>
                </div>
            )
        }
    },
    save: props => {
        const {
      className,
      attributes: { mapHTML }
    } = props;
renderMap()
        return (
            <div id='google-map'>
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

Comment: The `save` functions job is to translate the block attributes attributes into HTML and save it into post_content. Why would you need to render your map during that process?

Comment: I just learned what the `save` function does which didn't work with what I thought it did. Anyways I need to display the map on the front-end. I think I figured out how I'll do that.

Comment: I usually enqueue a separate JS file for rendering a Google Map on the frontend.